# Magento 2: Observer or Plugin for Mass Update Product Attribute

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer, product-attribute, massaction

I have a custom attribute that I need to observe after the mass update product has been finished, this custom attribute is related to a category in another custom table, so if this custom attribute value changed I need to assign a new category id to the product. My question is what observer or plugin is suitable for this kind of action? i also need to get the previous attribute value and the new attribute value

Answer (score 0):

You can use **catalog_product_attribute_update_before** event for this.

> In file `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Action.php` this
> event has been dispatched before updating the products.